# Opengl отрисовка обьектов

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

При "стандартном" методе отрисовки обьектов, используя перспективную проэкцию glFrustum(-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 100), возникают явные проблемы с отрисовкой обьектов вблизи. Когда я "подлетаю" камерой к обьэкту на расстояние менее 1 эдиницы, он просто пропадает, причем он не уходит за камеру - математически, он все еще находится в поле зрения камеры, но она его не отрисовывает. В функции glFrustum есть переменные zNear и zFar. И если с zFar все понятно (фактически этот параметр отвечает за дальность прорисовки), то вот zNear работает странно - при указании значения ниже 1, оно не только не начинает отрисовывать обьекты поближе, но еще и "разтягивает" камеру. Вот пример программы

```
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    int posZ = -1;

    glewInit();
    glfwInit();

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(600, 600, "Untitled", 0, 0);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glFrustum(-1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 100);

    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(0, 0, posZ);
        glVertex3f(1, 0, posZ);
        glVertex3f(1, 1, posZ);
        glEnd();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

В начале я создал переменную posZ. Если она меньше, чем -1, то все рисуется (с учетом дальности прорисовки конечно же). Если posZ равна, к примеру, -0.5f, то ничего не рисуется, хотя, в теории, треугольник все еще должен находиться в поле зрения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При выполнении `glFrustum` координата `z` будет отсекаться по диапазону от `-near` до `-far`, то бишь от `-1` до `-100` в данном случае. Соответственно если `posZ` равна, к примеру, `-0.5f`, то в диапазон она не попадает и отсекается. Отрицательность координаты возникает, так как ось `z` направлена в сторону камеры.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю, рассмотрев рисунок, я понял в чем дело

Answer (score 0):

При уменьшении дистанции отсечения zNear, нужно также и уменьшать отрезание по осям X и Y. Например, при значении zNear = 0.1f, значения left, right, bottom, top также должны равняться 0.1f. В коде, выглядит примерно так:

```
glFrustum(xLeft * zNear, xRight * zNear, yBottom * zNear, yTop * zNear, 
zNear, zFar)
```